# How to extract body of the mail, when there is content disposition?

Tags: php, email, cakephp, email-parsing

How to extract body of the mail, when there is content disposition?

header1

```
Accept-Language: en-US
Content-Language: en-US
X-MS-Has-Attach: yes
X-MS-TNEF-Correlator:
x-originating-ip: [x.x.x.x]
Content-Type: application/pkcs7-mime; smime-type=signed-data;
    name="smime.p7m"
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="smime.p7m"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
MIME-Version: 1.0
```

header2:

```
   Accept-Language: en-US
    Content-Language: en-US
    X-MS-Has-Attach:
    X-MS-TNEF-Correlator:
    x-originating-ip: [x.x.x.x]
    Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
        boundary="_000_A61C9CD725DF1C4FA94C13EC538A38BEEaz18ex3004_"
    MIME-Version: 1.0
```

when i sign the mail and send, the header of the mail is in format "header1" , when i sent the mail without signing it, the header of the mail is in format "header2"..

i am currently using `" getMessageBody()" method` from `mimemailparser.class.php` file to extract body of the message..

on signed mail, i am not able to retrieve the body of the message, it is returning empty body on using `"getmessagebody()" method`, but on unsigned mail it is able to retrieve the body of the message..

On checking the signed and unsigned mail headers, there is difference, how can the body of the mail can be extracted on signed mail (header1)?

Comment: Can you post a link to the source of the class you are using?

Comment: @Cypher i am using this library function "https://code.google.com/p/php-mime-mail-parser/"

Answer (score 0):

look at the method `getMessageBody()` in the class, at the following part of code:

```
foreach($this->parts as $part) {
  if ($this->getPartContentType($part) == $mime_types[$type]) {
    $headers = $this->getPartHeaders($part);
    $body    = $this->decode($this->getPartBody($part), array_key_exists('content-transfer-encoding', $headers) ? $headers['content-transfer-encoding'] : '');
    break;
  }
}
```

Class splits MIME message into parts and there may be a situation, when body is divided into several parts, but the code decode only the first part (it may be empty in your case).
Try to modify this code like this:

```
foreach ($this->parts as $part) {
  if ($this->getPartContentType($part) == $mime_types[$type]) {
    $headers = $this->getPartHeaders($part);
    $body   .= $this->decode($this->getPartBody($part), array_key_exists('content-transfer-encoding', $headers) ? $headers['content-transfer-encoding'] : '');
  }
}
```

Comment: i have checked on this. the code is already in the proposed format without break..